# How do you do a for each to create nodes for each element of a node property?

Tags: neo4j

I have nodes representing algorithms with the *author* property. I want to create nodes for people who are in the author of the algorithms and create WORKED_ON relationships between these people and the algorithms. So I tried:

```
FOREACH (p:author IN al:Algorithm | CREATE (p:PERSON).
(p)-[:WORKED_ON]->(al:Algorithm))
```

But it returns:

```
Invalid input ':': expected "IN" (line 2, column 11 (offset: 156)).
"FOREACH (p:author IN al:Algorithm | CREATE (p:PERSON)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that the author property contains a list of names , separated by a comma, you could do something like this

```
MATCH (a:Algorithm)

FOREACH( authorName IN SPLIT(a.author,',') |
    MERGE (p:Person {name:authorName})
    MERGE (p)-[:WORKED_ON]->(a)
)
```

NOTE : for the `MERGE` to work fast, you should set

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE
```

Answer (score 0):

`FOREACH` works on a collection, so you would have to collect the `Algorithm` nodes first. Something like,

```
MATCH (n:Algorithm) with collect(n) as algos
FOREACH(a in algos | CREATE (p:Person {name: a.author})-[:WORKED_ON]->(a))
```

However, there may be a simpler way create those Person nodes,

```
MATCH (a:Algorithm) 
CREATE (a)<-[:WORKED_ON]-(:Person {name: a.author})
```

Comment: Many thanks ! However it creates duplicates when one person worked on different algorithms

Comment: if 'name' is unique, then this may work,
MATCH (a:Algorithm) 
MERGE (p:Person {name: a.author}) 
MERGE (a)<-[:WORKED_ON]-(p)